# I turned on change tracking in Microsoft Word 2016 but new text isn't underlined

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I opened a document in MS Word 2016 and turned on change tracking, but when I type new text, it isn't underlined as I would expect. I see a vertical red bar on the left, but I want to see all new text underlined (and all deleted text in strikeout).

Answer (score 0):

In the Review menu, Tracking section, change the dropdown from "Simple Markup" (the default) to "All Markup". This will highlight all new/deleted text with underline/strikeout.

Also, even when Simple Markup is selected, you can click on the vertical red bar and see the exact changes for that section.

(Based on what I found when Googling, I believe this applies to MS Word 2013 as well, but I don't have that version to try it out.)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working for me.  I have "All Markup" selected, and see changes in the review window, and names on the side, but my typing is plain black with no annotations at all.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ what version of Word are you using?

Comment: Office 365 ProPlus is the best I can come up with for a version, build 1803.